# How to check if string1 digits can be rearranged into string2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I want to write a function that accepts str1 and str2 and checks if str1 digits can be rearranged into str2.

Currently stuck at this:

My code works fine until str2 won't have any double digits.
How can I fix this?

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {
    str1 = str1.split('');
    str2 = str2.split('');

    let result = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < str1.length; j++) {
            if (str2[i] === str1[j]) {
                result.push(str1[j]);
            }
        }
    }


    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        if (result[i] === result[i + 1]) {
            result.splice(i, 1);
            --i;
        }
    }
    return result.join('') === str2.join('')
}
console.log(scramble('rkqodlw','world'));
console.log(scramble('aabbcamaomsccdd','commas')); //heres the problem
```

Comment: Sort those arrays, and make them unique

Comment: The question title and the examples in the posted code do not make sense together. If one string's set of characters can be "rearranged into" another string, the answer must be "no" if the strings are not the same length.

Comment: Digits means you're working with numbers, not strings: check if the product of all digits is the same, after checking that both numbers have the same length (because if not, you return false). Just remember to use [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) unless you're fine with "collisions" for large numbers (e.g. more than one number yielding the same product result, because of int/long overflow). Unless you meant "letters"? (although even then, `char` is a number)

Answer (score 0):

A simple method is to check, whether all characters from the second string are contained in the the first one. To deal with double characters in the second string, remove each found character from the first string.

This of course only returns the correct result if the extra characters in the first string don't matter ...

```js
function checkstrings(string1, string2) {
  let s1 = [...string1]  //convert string1 and 
    , s2 = [...string2]; //string2 into arrays of char
  for (let c of s2) {  
    let i = s1.indexOf(c); //check if c from s2 is contained in s1
    if (i == -1)  //if not found result can' be true 
      return false;
  
    s1.splice(i, 1);  //remove c from s1
  }

  return true;
}

console.log(checkstrings("rkqodlw", "world"));
console.log(checkstrings("aabbcamaomsccdd", "commas")); 
console.log(checkstrings("aabbcamaomsccdd", "commmas"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a count of the various characters in each and use that as comparison.

Following uses `Map` objects then iterates the str2 counts to make sure the test string (str1) contains equal or greater count for each character in str2

```js
// helper function to map character counts
const charCount = (str) =>{
    return [...str].reduce((a,c)=> a.set(c, (a.get(c)||0)+1), new Map)
}

function scramble(str1, str2) {
   const s2Counts = charCount(str2),
         s1Counts = charCount(str1);
        
   return [...s2Counts.entries()].every(([char,count]) => s1Counts.get(char) >= count)
}
console.log(scramble('rkqodlw','world')); // expect true
console.log(scramble('aabbcamaomsccdd','commas')); // expect true

console.log(scramble('fobar','foobar')); // expect false
```